# Android iterate RecycleView's hidden items with TalkBack

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility, talkback

I have a recycleview which has more than 10 items inside. Because it has more than 10 items, it shows only 4 items at one time. Problem comes with TalkBack, i want to iterate in list with drag left/right actions but after 4. item focus goes on another view components on layout. How can i iterate all items of recycleview with Talkback?

Edit:
I use my own accessibility delegate like this:

```
mRecyclerView.setAccessibilityDelegate(mAccessibilityDelegate);


public class AccessibilityDelegate extends View.AccessibilityDelegate {

private Assistant mAssistant;

public AccessibilityDelegate(Assistant assistant)
{
    mAssistant = assistant;
}

@Override
public void sendAccessibilityEvent(View host, int eventType) {
    if(!mAssistant.isSpeaking() && mAssistant.isRecognizerAvailable())
    {
        super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean performAccessibilityAction(View host, int action, Bundle args) {
    if(!mAssistant.isSpeaking() && mAssistant.isRecognizerAvailable())
    {
        return super.performAccessibilityAction(host, action, args);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    super.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(host, event);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    return super.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
}

@Override
public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
}

@Override
public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup host, View child, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(host, child, event);
}

@Override
public AccessibilityNodeProvider getAccessibilityNodeProvider(View host) {
    return super.getAccessibilityNodeProvider(host);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you by mistake turn on talkback ? and trying to come out from this. or doing some app to work ?

Comment: No, i want to develop an app with accessiblity features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few trials i found the problem.

To override RecycleView's accessibility features extend RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.

```
    //mRecyclerView.setAccessibilityDelegate(mAccessibilityDelegate);
    RVAccessibilityDelegate rvAccessibilityDelegate = new RVAccessibilityDelegate(mRecyclerView, mAssistant);
    mRecyclerView.setAccessibilityDelegateCompat(rvAccessibilityDelegate);
```

In addition if you want to disable announces like "showing item 1 of 6" simply comment out super.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(host, event)

```
public class RVAccessibilityDelegate extends RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate {

private Assistant mAssistant;

public RVAccessibilityDelegate(RecyclerView recyclerView, Assistant assistant) {
    super(recyclerView);
    mAssistant = assistant;
}

@Override
public boolean performAccessibilityAction(View host, int action, Bundle args) {
    if(!mAssistant.isSpeaking() && mAssistant.isRecognizerAvailable())
    {
        return super.performAccessibilityAction(host, action, args);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
}

@Override
public void sendAccessibilityEvent(View host, int eventType) {
    if(!mAssistant.isSpeaking() && mAssistant.isRecognizerAvailable())
    {
        super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType);
    }
}

@Override
public void sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    //super.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(host, event);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    return super.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
}

@Override
public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup host, View child, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(host, child, event);
}

@Override
public AccessibilityNodeProviderCompat getAccessibilityNodeProvider(View host) {
    return super.getAccessibilityNodeProvider(host);
}
```

}

Comment: What is Assistant class, is it from Accessibility?

Comment: No, it just a custom class. Do you have trouble with this solution?

Comment: I have a same sort of requirement, But I don't know when assistant has finished speaking. Can you please check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782169/is-there-any-callback-or-anything-any-parameter-in-event-or-nodeinfo-to-know-a

Comment: dont care of assistant, its my custom object for some kind of job, just delete it: 
@Override
public void sendAccessibilityEvent(View host, int eventType) {
   super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType);
}

Comment: What is **Assistant**?

Comment: Hi in my case on recycler view , i want to change order of accessiblity, how it can be achieve.. please help