# Is there any callback or anything (any parameter in event or nodeInfo) to know accessibility service (TalkBack) has finished reading?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I have an application requirement to announce text in a list view. The list view item gets added at run time. I have to announce them one by one. I searched on google and in android docs, but I could not reach there.

Please help me, how to know accessibility services finished reading the text?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you announcing them for all users, or just for accessibility purposes?  You could use accessibility announcements and let TalkBack decide when to announce things.  Otherwise my recommendation would be to shut the announcement off entirely when TalkBack is on.  Both of these are simple, I await clarification before posting code.

Comment: It is for only accessibility purpose (for blind persons). I have to read all the items for them. I am using talkback. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer... don't do it this way!  This is silliness.  Just use the accessibility features available to you and let TalkBack (or other potential screen reader) manage it for you.  Just use this utility function.

```
public static void announceForAccessibility(Context context, String message) {
    AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);

    if (manager.isEnabled()) {

        AccessibilityEvent e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
        e.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT);
        e.setClassName(context.getClass().getName());
        e.setPackageName(context.getPackageName());
        e.getText().add(message);

        manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same. Just I want to know the end of reading the sent message and send the  next one to manager!! Thanks :)

Comment: Just let TalkBack prioritize.